# How to Implement Request Reply pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, activemq-classic, message-queue, apache-camel

I am trying to implement the [request-reply pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/RequestReply.html) using Camel, Spring and ActiveMQ.
What I need to do is reading CSV file line-by-line.
Then for every line:

1. Construct request based on line values from the CSV
2. Send the request to the queue
3. Other component needs to pick up the message, process the request and send the response to another message queue (known to producer, so the producer could pick up the response).

I got the code below working.
Now lets say that in the Processor I create the response.

**My questions are:**

1. How can I send the response back?
2. How can I consume the response?

---

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Main().run(args);
    }

    public void configure() {
        from("file:/Users/aviad/ws/integ/src/data?fileName=lines.txt&noop=true&idempotent=true")
        .split()
        .tokenize("\\n")
        .inOut("activemq:req");

        from("activemq:req")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                System.out.println("jmscorrelationid=" + exchange.getIn().getHeader("jmscorrelationid"));
                System.out.println("jmsdestination=" + exchange.getIn().getHeader("jmsdestination"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement Request-Reply pattern using ActiveMQ, Camel and Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243433/implement-request-reply-pattern-using-activemq-camel-and-spring)

Comment: not a duplicate. rather more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel sends automatic a response back if there is a JMSReplyTo set on the incoming JMS message. So in your 2nd route, when the message reaches the end of the route, then the JMS consumer, will send back the message "as its currently is" as the reply message, to the JMSReplyTo destination, with the given JMSCorrelationID.

There is a number of options you can set on JMS endpoint to disable automatic sending back reply. Or to specify a named reply queue etc. See the JMS page for all its options: http://camel.apache.org/jms

As you use inOut from the 1st route, then Camel will do request-reply over JMS. And by default it uses temporary queues. But you can also tell Camel to use named queues (fixed queues as we call it). See the JMS docs: http://camel.apache.org/jms

And notice the tip on the top of the JMS page: http://camel.apache.org/jms. It refers you to a section on the page about details about request/reply. So go read that.

Comment: thanks! After reading all the docs you mentioned I still fail to understand what I need to add on the first root to be able to run some code when the response arrives. Any hints?

Comment: Just add more to the route after the inOut, eg .inOut("activemq:req").process(...)...